# create-quip-app do not create correct folder structure

Tags: quip, liveapps

Ran the below command as per documentation (https://quip.com/dev/liveapps), but the system did not create correct folder structure as provided:

```
npm install -g create-quip-app
create-quip-app my-app
```

Expected outcome:

[image]

Real outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is expected as of right now. The folder structure is different, but the commands should still run as expected. Are you encountering an issue as a result of the new folder structure?